# What is the "eosio" account re:EOS blockchains?

Tags: eos

When configuring and installing an EOS blockchain, you're required to use the "eosio" account as the block producing account or blocks aren't signed. I haven't been able to find much info. however about this pseudo account as it appears to come w/the software by default.

From EOSIO documentation, the "eosio" account is an authorizing account, used to bootstrap EOSIO nodes. But is it stored someplace, or just the default "root" account for EOS blockchains?

You even use this account to create new accounts.

My question is, where is its private key? Is this the key set in the genesis.json file? Can I use another account to configure my blockchain? I would imagine so b/c you specify it at the cmd. line, otherwise the parameter wouldn't be needed.

I'm just frustrated by the lack of documentation surrounding EOS and kindly request help from the community.

UPDATE: 7/13/2018

I changed the "producer-name" to another value but then the blockchain doesn't sign transactions and it sits idle. This is why I'm confused about "eosio." Its key is configured in the config.ini but it doesn't appear that you can change the "producer-name," which is fine, but then why have a "-p" cmd. line  parameter? It's just not making sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

its private key is stored at config.ini

```
# Tuple of [public key, WIF private key] (may specify multiple times) (eosio::producer_plugin)
private-key = ["EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV","5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3"]
```

The second value is the private key.

In addition I think that you can use another account to configure your blockchain . EOSIO is just the testing account .

So i suppose that you can use another block producer if you use another producer name and account with different keys at config.ini

Check this : https://medium.com/coinmonks/test-4fbd38fdc4e8 chapter 4

Comment: I changed the "producer-name" to another value but then the blockchain doesn't sign transactions and it sits idle. This is why I'm confused about "eosio." Its key is configured in the config.ini but it doesn't appear you can change the name, which is fine, but then why have a "-p" cmd. line parameter? It's just not making sense to me.

Comment: The -p is just for the permissions. Just keep in mind that you are in a TEST-NET in order to check the functionality of your smart-contracts and so on. Did you read the article? I think you can change the configuration of config.ini

Comment: Yes, I read the article, and in detail. Many times in fact. When I change the -p parameter, I get an error. Why?